# Please reopen 'When clichés contend'?

Tags: support

I've now supplemented [Can I use "contend" without a preposition?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/182000/meaning-of-contend-when-clich%C3%A9s-contend) with an addedum concernig why it shouldn't be esteemed as "off-topic".

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing in the edit [as it stands at the time of this answer] which adds more information indicating that all of the existing answers are insufficient, that there is nothing which answers the question.

One answer did misunderstand the phrase in question, but a comment on that explains why it's wrong (and thus that comment helps to answer your question). The other answer actually answers the question.

When you edit a question with a view to re-opening, the edit must be substantive. You need to provide [that is, **add,** not merely reference] further evidence and documentation which supports your question and which is not fully covered in the answers when taken collectively. I don't think this has happened in this case.

Since you are interested in further definitions of *contend,* I offer [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/contend_1):

> to compete in order to win something:
>   *There are three world-class tennis players contending for this title*

If you substitute *compete* for *contend,* the phrase in your question makes sense. The question as it stands — even with the current edit — is correctly closed as General Reference.

Answer (score 0):

I've [edited](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/182000/revisions) the question to focus more on the missing preposition than on the meaning of the word "contend" which is fairly clear from the dictionary references. This should resolve the close reason and, hopefully, people will now vote to reopen the question.